# Shared Hosting CPU usage increase to 100% - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

### Problem

My shared hosting CPU usage increase to 100%.

### Error Image

[image]

### Framework

Wordpress version 5.5.1 
All Plugins was updated to the latest version.

### Question

May I know what cause this and how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

#### Explanation

This problem is cause by low memory setting. Because if system cannot get the memory that they need, they will look for memory over the cpu. That why there is a high cpu usage.

I just changed the
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); 
to 
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

In normal circumstance, at minimum, you have to set it to minimum 128M.